# Windows Form, center dialog over parent control (floating)

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I have a dialog that should always open over a datagrid and more precisely over the center of the datagrid, even when the app is resized. It's a MDI app.
The code I am using right now is the following:

```
var dialog = new Dialog();
var location = myGrid.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
dialog.Left = location.X + (myGrid.Width / 2) - (dialog.Width / 2);
dialog.Top = location.Y + (myGrid.Height / 2) - (dialog.Height / 2);
```

It is working **only** when the MDI is maximized. If it's resized, the position of the dialog is completely wrong.

Comment: This snippet is very incomplete.  What's the dialog's StartPosition property setting?  Being off could only easily be explained if this is not a dialog at all but actually an MDI child.  This can only work in all possible cases if this code is written in an event handler for the dialog's Load event.  So it is not affected by auto-scaling.

Comment: ah ah , so the dialog itself should set the position and not the actual caller. Yes, it's a MDI app